# Python "del" syntax error when used as a variable name

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse, del

I am building a todo-list CLI and it requires a ***del*** argument for deleting an entry from the list. The CLI usage is as given below

```
$ ./todo help
Usage :-
$ ./todo add "todo item"  # Add a new todo
$ ./todo ls               # Show remaining todos
$ ./todo del NUMBER       # Delete a todo
$ ./todo done NUMBER      # Complete a todo
$ ./todo help             # Show usage
$ ./todo report           # Statistics
```

But in python( I am using python 3.8.3) when using the argparse module for parsing the arguments from command line the code for the above specified feature is as follows

`parser.add_argument("--del", type=int, help="Delete a todo")`

The problem arises since del is a reserved keyword by python for completely different purpose and so it gives a syntax error when reading that line of code

`print (args.del)`

[syntax highlight image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/35031326/103398463-d78aad00-4b62-11eb-9855-e430952499a2.png)

Error message is as follows

```
File "todo.py", line 24
    if args.del:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

[syntax error image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/35031326/103398446-c2ae1980-4b62-11eb-94f3-2174607c9a56.png)

*Is there a solution to use **del** as per requirements of the project.*

Comment: `del` is a reserved keyword.

Comment: why not change `del` to `delete` as `del` is a reserved keyword

Comment: yeah i know that too but the moderators of the project asked to use "del" as a CLI argument, what is the possible solution to this. Check the usage described in the question body.

Comment: Here is the GitHub repo issue I made, if it helps in any way. https://github.com/nseadlc-2020/package-todo-cli-task/issues/51

Comment: Use `dest=` to change the eventual name of the argument to a non-reserved keyword https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#dest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`dest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#dest) parameter can be passed to `argparse.add_argument` to change the eventual attribute name that the argument will be bound to. You can use this to change "del" to a non-reserved keyword attribute name

```
parser.add_argument('--del', type=int, help='Delete a todo', dest='should_delete')
```

Answer (score 2):

`del` is a reserved keyword. It cannot be used as an attribute.

In this case, you can use a string to dynamically access this attribute, however:

```
getattr(args, "del")
```

However, it is probably better to change this name.

Answer (score 2):

As `del` is a reserved keyword it cannot be used. However you can use `dest` to create a custom attribute and not use the auto generated attribute.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--del', dest='delete')
parser.parse_args('--del XXX'.split())
```

Results in: `Namespace(delete='XXX')`